# How to get data in format in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the data in table format from a SQL Server stored procedure to mail as html.

I have tried this in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SIGN VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @MailSubject = 'Scenario Wise Report as on - '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE() - 1, 103)

SET @body ='<html><head>
<table><tr>
<td valign="top"><table border="1" class="custom_class"><thead><tr><th colspan="9" bgcolor=yellow>Scenario Wise Report</th></tr></thead>
<tr><th>Scenario</th><th>Count</th></tr>
<tr>Email id not registered</tr>
<tr>119 Out of time frame</tr>
<tr>chargeback</tr>
<tr>90 out of time frame</tr>
<tr>direct credit</tr>
<tr>dispute form received</tr>
<tr>csa case</tr>
<tr>email received</tr>
<tr>reminder 1</tr>
<tr>reminder 2</tr>
<tr>reminder 3</tr>
<tr>exception</tr>
<tr>fallout</tr>

<tbody>'

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT  email AS 'td','', out_of_time   AS 'td','' ,chargeback AS 'td','',out_of_time_90 AS 'td','',direct_credit AS 'td','',
dispute AS 'td','',csa AS 'td','',email_received AS 'td','',reminder_1 AS 'td','',reminder_2 AS 'td','',reminder_3 AS 'td','',
exception AS 'td','',fallout AS 'td'
FROM @count
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
'</table></body></html>' 

SET @body = @body + @xml + '`
```

I want my result like this:-

```
Scenario                  Count

Email id not registered     60
119 Out of time frame      395
chargeback                 151
90 out of time frame         0
direct credit               43
dispute form received       18
csa case                    18
email received              15
reminder 1                 145
reminder 2                   0
reminder 3                   0
exception                   20
fallout                     45

Total                      910
```

But I am getting this result now:

```
Scenario                 Count
Email id not registered    60
119 Out of time frame     395
chargeback                151
90 out of time frame        0
direct credit              43
dispute form received      18
csa case                   18
email received             15
reminder 1                145
reminder 2                  0
reminder 3                  0
exception                  20
fallout                    45
Total                     910
```

Comment: Firstly in what environment are you seeing this result exactly ?  Not all environments are set up to interpret HTML. How are you triggering the query, and how are you viewing the output? Your code above doesn't even show how you actually create the final output. Secondly a lot of your HTML is not valid. You cannot write content directly into a `tr` (table row) - you must put at least one `td` (table cell) within the row, and then the cell must contain the actual content

Comment: What you are getting and you are looking for seems same result to me. What is the issue?

Comment: P.s. it would help a lot more if you showed the raw HTML output from your query, instead of formatted text